# Менять цвет фона за N дней до конкретной даты

Tags: javascript, jquery, дата, datetime, momentjs

Пробовал реализовать уведомление посредством изменения цвета фона, за 2 дня до определенной даты. Но закрашивает все поля, вне зависимости от разности дат. Подскажите, как правильно это сделать?

```
<table>
  <tr><td class='data'>2022-02-25</td></tr>
  <tr><td class='data'>2022-02-28</td></tr>
  <tr><td class='data'>2022-03-28</td></tr>
</table>

let total = document.querySelectorAll('.data')
total.forEach(function(user) {
  let now = moment(new Date()); 
  let end = moment(user.innerText); 
  let duration = moment.duration(end.diff(now));
  let days = duration.asDays();
  if(parseInt(days) <= 2){
    $('.data').addClass("red")
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".data").forEach(function(el) {
  // дни = милисекунды / секунды / минуты / часы
  let duration = (new Date(el.innerText) - new Date()) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
  if (duration <= 2) {
    el.classList.add("red");
  }
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td class='data'>2022-02-25</td></tr>
  <tr><td class='data'>2022-02-26</td></tr>
  <tr><td class='data'>2022-02-27</td></tr>
  <tr><td class='data'>2022-02-28</td></tr>
  <tr><td class='data'>2122-01-01</td></tr>
  <tr><td class='data'>2222-01-01</td></tr>
</table>
```